# Help with MySQL date operation

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have two columns: duration (int) and dateCol (date) in a table.
How should i proceed if i want to know when CURDATE() - dateCol will iqual to duration.

**ie**: CURDATE() -  dateCol (2010-05-08) = duration (14 days), and then send an e-amil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want you can use [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
DATEDIFF(NOW(), last_email_date) >= 14
```

An alternative method is to interval subtraction:

```
CURDATE() - interval 14 day >= last_email_date
```

The second can be faster if there is a suitable index.

Note that I've chosen to use an inequality test instead of an equality because this will handle missed emails if your process is offline for one day and is restarted the next day. You should mark the row as handled when you've handled it to prevent more than one email being sent. This will also prevent multiple emails being sent if your process runs more than once per day (this could happen if you restart it to upgrade / bug fix).

Comment: Thanks. I think i ll use equality, cause i need the difference iqual 14.

Comment: @jartaud: That's OK. If you say that, it means that it's better to not send an email at all than to send it one day too late. If that's what you want, you should use an equality.

Comment: suppose we have dateCol iquals to:
2010-05-18, 2010-05-08, 2010-05-10, ...(CURDATE() - interval 14 day > dateCol) AS TEST will return nothing, but TEST = 2010-05-08. (if CURDATE() is 2010-05-22).

Comment: @jartaud: Yes, sorry - off by one. `>=` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) = datecol
```

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions (the second one from Mark Byers) work.